# XCode 11.4 XCTest - Mock object does not see convenience initializer from the real object class

Tags: inheritance, ios13, xctest, swift5, xcode11.4

I'm trying to understand if there is something within `XCTest` framework that **prevents my test class from seeing convenience initializer** defined in a class for the module I'm testing? I'm using @testable import to override and subclass non-open classes.

The tests were running correctly before. Is this some XCode 11.4 bug?

I have multiple versions of this error, every time it is the convenience initializer, even if it is declared public.

**Error Missing argument for parameter 'repository' in call**

```
//Inside FrameworkModule

public class RealObject {

    init(repository: SomeRepository) {
       //designated initializer
    }


    convenience override init() {
    // Use default repository
    }
}

//Inside Test class:
@testable import FrameworkModule

class MockObject: RealObject {
    //Inherits initializers from RealObject

}

class TestHelper: NSObject {   
var mockObject: MockObject!

}
    override init() {
       mockObject = MockObject() //Error Missing argument for parameter 'repository' in call
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling with the same problem, and found out that this is due to a change mentioned in [Xcode 11.4's release notes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_4_release_notes).

> Convenience initializer inheritance for subclasses defined outside the
> module that defines the base class now comes with additional
> restrictions. When these subclasses have a base class with non-public
> designated initializers, they no longer automatically inherit
> convenience initializers from their superclasses. To restore this
> automatic inheritance behavior, the base class must ensure that all of
> its designated initializers are public or open. (51249311)

I believe if you make all of your designated initializers public, you should be able to see it from your unit test class.